# Botão Bootstrap com AngularJs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

Como eu posso mudar a classe do Botão?

```
    <!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.1.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="ButtonsCtrl">
        <h4>Radio &amp; Uncheckable Radio</h4>
        <pre>{{radioModel}}</pre>

        <div class="btn-group">
            <label class="ng-class: {{BA}}" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'A'">A</label>
            <label class="ng-class: {{BB}}" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'B'">B</label>
            <label class="{{BC}}" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'C'">C</label>
            <label class="{{BD}}" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'D'">D</label>
            <label class="{{BE}}" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'E'">E</label>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ButtonsCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.singleModel = 1;
    $scope.radioModel = '';
    $scope.BA = 'btn btn-default';
    $scope.BB = 'btn btn-default';
    $scope.BC = 'btn btn-default';
    $scope.BD = 'btn btn-default';
    $scope.BE = 'btn btn-default';

    $scope.checkModel = {
        A: false,
        B: false,
        C: false,
        D: false,
        E: false
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você chegou perto. A sintaxe para `ng-class` precisa ser ajustada como no exemplo abaixo:

```js
angular
    .module('ui.bootstrap.demo', [])
    .controller('ButtonsCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.BA = 'btn btn-default';
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app='ui.bootstrap.demo'>
  <div ng-controller="ButtonsCtrl">
    <label ng-class="BA" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'A'">A</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

<sub>**Update**: Tratando o exemplo nos comentários</sub>

O formato de avaliação ternária do ng-class é o seguinte:

```
ng-class="avaliação ? 'classeCasoVerdadeiro' : 'classeCasoFalso'"
```

O exemplo mencionado ficaria assim:

```
ng-class="radioModel === 'A' ? 'btn btn-primary' : 'btn btn-default'"
```

Comment: Eu entendi a mudança. Eu gostaria de fazer mais ou menos algo assim: ng-if="{{ radioModel }} === 'A' ? BA = 'btn btn-primary' : BA = 'btn btn-default'"

Comment: Ou melhor: ng-if="{{ radioModel }} === 'A' ? ng-class='btn btn-primary' : ng-class='btn btn-default'"

Comment: @LuisSouza Eu atualizei a resposta com seu exemplo.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente!

Comment: @LuisSouza fico feliz em ler isso!

Comment: Como eu poderia pegar os dados de um Json? Alterando os botões.   http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/77777/repeat-n%C3%A3o-funciona-angular